# Sylius add new zone scope

Tags: symfony, sylius, sylius-resource, sylius-1.3

I'm using the framework Sylius v1.4.7, I want to add a new scope in the choice list in zone form but I don't know how I can do that. Could you help me please ?

I override this class ZoneChoiceType but in vain, I still have the default values in scope select input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a guide for [form customization](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/customization/form.html).
The right type to customize is `Sylius\Bundle\AddressingBundle\Form\Type\ZoneTypeChoiceType`, or `Sylius\Bundle\AddressingBundle\Form\Type\ZoneType`

You can also [use configuration](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/0c8f36228e5973c83fb57613162754226bc4711a/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/sylius/sylius_addressing.yml#L4-L8) to add a new scope.

Comment: Thank you @victor vasiloi, I add a new scope by using the configuration file 

`sylius_addressing:
  scopes:
    shipping: sylius.form.zone.scopes.shipping
    tax: sylius.form.zone.scopes.tax
    all: sylius.form.zone.scopes.all
    shipping_cost: sylius.form.zone.scopes.shipping_cost`